# Best way to add an element to every array in a mutidimentional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to add an element to every array in my multidimensional array.

My array is like this:

```
 Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [RatingFactorPreferenceID] => 10
            [PreferenceID] => 45
            [RatedValue] => 1
            [CreatedOn] => 1326779061
            [CreatedBy] => 25
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [RatingFactorPreferenceID] => 20
            [PreferenceID] => 45
            [RatedValue] => 2
            [CreatedOn] => 1326779061
            [CreatedBy] => 25
        )

)
```

I want to add  `[RatingID] => 2` to both arrays, then my final array would look like:

```
 Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [RatingID] => 2
            [RatingFactorPreferenceID] => 10
            [PreferenceID] => 45
            [RatedValue] => 1
            [CreatedOn] => 1326779061
            [CreatedBy] => 25
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [RatingID] => 2
            [RatingFactorPreferenceID] => 20
            [PreferenceID] => 45
            [RatedValue] => 2
            [CreatedOn] => 1326779061
            [CreatedBy] => 25
        )

)
```

I can loop over my array and do this, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Are these data coming from an sql statement? if so maybe you can do it from query level instead of php

Comment: @andreas no it is a php array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$array = array_map(function ($a) { return $a + array('RatingID' => 2); }, $array);
```

This still loops, but behind the scenes, if you prefer that.
You could also use [`array_walk`](http://www.php.net/array_walk), but that's really just looping disguised in a different syntax.

Comment: actually 2 is not a hard coded value . when i tried to use $var = 1 ; and array('RatingID' => $var) inside arry_map function . it says , undefined variable  $var . why is that

Comment: Because any variables outside the anonymous function are not in scope within the function. You'll need to use `function ($a) use ($var) { ... }` to include them in the scope. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php. If you don't feel comfortable with this syntax, a simple loop is probably the better choice.

Answer (score 1):

@deceze's answer is good but instantiating a second array and using the array union operator (`+`) is needlessly complex. Keep it simple:

```
$new_array = array_map(
  function( $inner_array ) {
    $inner_array[ 'RatingID' ] = 2;

    return $inner_array;
  },

  $orig_array
);
```

Comment: Depends on how you define "needlessly complex". I for one find something done in two statements that can be done in one expression "needlessly complex". If you're going that far, just use a three-line `foreach` to do the same thing instead of a 7-line `array_map`... :o)

Comment: @deceze "Complex" both in terms of readability and computation. I love a good one-liner as much as the next guy but allocating a new array and then performing a merge in order to save a newline is just vanity.

Comment: @Topener Yes it is. I generally assume 5.3+ unless the OP specifies otherwise, mostly because the non-closure callback syntax makes my eye twitch.

Comment: `array + another_array` is an idiom I'm very used to, it just seems very straight forward to me. As for performance... if you're really that worried about it, use `foreach ($array as &$arr)`, the overhead of calling the function repeatedly is much worse.

Comment: Kind of, but the OP doesn't have 100,000 items in his arrays. http://codepad.viper-7.com/WSMr97

Comment: Indeed, so it makes even less of a difference.

Answer (score 0):

I think array_walk is the best option

```
$array = array(
            array(
                'RatingFactorPreferenceID' => 10,
                'PreferenceID' => 45,
                'RatedValue' => 1,
                'CreatedOn' => 1326779061,
                'CreatedBy' => 25
            ),
            array(
                'RatingFactorPreferenceID' => 20,
                'PreferenceID' => 45,
                'RatedValue' => 2,
                'CreatedOn' => 1326779061,
                'CreatedBy' => 25,
            )
        );

function AddAtTop(&$act_array,$key){

    $act_array = array_merge(array('RatingID'=>2), $act_array);
}

array_walk($array, 'AddAtTop');

echo '<pre>';
print_r($array);
echo '</pre>';
```

This should work for you.